# How hide inversed data? Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping

I have 2 entities Product and User.
How i can hide user data in my Product query?

Example:

Product

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $user;
```

And user

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $products;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"?

Comment: I'm working with Symfony2 API and ExtJs. If i use standart product repo for "findAll" action, it shows all product data and all mapped data from user entity, with  password, salt. I want hide user data from API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **serializer** to show what you want. In this case if you don't want to show the user of product this attribute does not have any kind of serializer.

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("ALL")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="my-attribute", type="string", nullable=false)
     * @Serializer\Expose
     * @Serializer\Groups({"anyKindOfGroup"})
     */
     protected $attributeWhichIsSerializer;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="products")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    */
    protected $user;

(...)
```

Comment: Case resolved benatespina thx, now im using groups via serializer